# How to highlight text in the title?

Tags: qt, winapi, qtgui, win32gui

I print the calculation results in the end of window title text. I want to highlight them. How to change text colour in the title and how can I make background for this text like in last versions of Microsoft Office?

---

If there's no way without drawing the non-client area myself I'd like to know how to draw the non-client area considering any system options set for windows titles.

Comment: There's no way without drawing the non-client area yourself.

Comment: Custom-drawing the non-client area of a window is VERY difficult to get right across multiple Windows versions, especially if you want to play nice with Visual Themes and Aero Glass.  You really should find a better and *standard* way to display your text.  Why do you have to display it on the title at all?